# What is the difference between * and *& in C++?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between * and *& in function parameters. For example,

What is the difference between this,

```
void a(SomeType *s)
{

}
```

and this,

```
void a(SomeType *&s)
{

}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `int` and `int &`?

Comment: `void a(SomeType *s)`: pass pointer `s` by value. `void a(SomeType *&s)`: Pass pointer `s` by reference.

Comment: @chris: Where should I use * and *&?

Comment: @user3335, The decision is the same as `int` vs `int &`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's add some "meat" to `a`:

```
void a1(SomeType *s)
{
    s = new SomeType;
}

void a2(SomeType *&s)
{
    s = new SomeType;
}
```

Now assume you have this code, which calls `a`:

```
void func()
{
    SomeType *p1 = nullptr;
    a1(p1);
    if (p == nullptr)
        std::cout << "p1 is null" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "p1 is not null" << std::endl;

    SomeType *p2 = nullptr;
    a2(p2);
    if (p == nullptr)
        std::cout << "p2 is null" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "p2 is not null" << std::endl;
}
```

`a1` accepts a pointer, so the variable `s` is a *copy of the pointer* `p1`. So when `a` returns, `p1` is still `nullptr` and the memory allocated inside `a1` leaks.

`a2` accepts a reference to a pointer, so `s` is an "alias" to `p2`. So when `a2` returns `p2` points to the memory allocated inside `a2`.

Generally, see [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). Then apply that knowledge to pointers.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a reference (using `&`) into a function, you can modify the value and the modifications will not be local.  If you don't pass a reference (no `&`), the modifications will be local to the function.

```
#include <cstdio>
int one = 1, two = 2;

// x is a pointer passed *by value*, so changes are local
void f1(int *x) { x = &two; }

// x is a pointer passed *by reference*, so changes are propagated
void f2(int *&x) { x = &two; }

int main()
{
    int *ptr = &one;
    std::printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr);
    f1(ptr);
    std::printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr);
    f2(ptr);
    std::printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*ptr = 1
*ptr = 1
*ptr = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In first case the function accepts the value of a pointer. In second case the function accepts non-constant reference to the pointer variable and that means that you can change this pointer location through the reference.